# How to overwrite clang libtooling -version option to display the version of my program

Tags: clang

I have developed a tool using Clang Libtooling and -help option says this about -version option:

-version                   - Display the version of this program

And when I execute this:

$ tool_name -version

LLVM (http://llvm.org/):

LLVM version 6.0.1

Optimized build.

Default target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

Host CPU: broadwell

It shows the version of clang being used for my program. But is there any way to show version information of my tool instead of clang's?

Something like:

$ tool_name -version

tool_name 2.0

I searched the clang document but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clang tools use LLVM's CommandLine library to parse command line arguments. It has its own [manual](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandLine.html), where you can find [SetVersionPrinter](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandLine.html#the-cl-setversionprinter-function) function.

Here is a small example:

```cpp
#include "clang/Tooling/CommonOptionsParser.h"
#include "clang/Tooling/Tooling.h"

using namespace clang;
using namespace clang::driver;
using namespace clang::tooling;

static llvm::cl::OptionCategory MyToolOptions("My Awesome Clang Tool");

int main(int Argc, const char **Argv) {
  llvm::cl::SetVersionPrinter(
      [](llvm::raw_ostream &OS) { OS << "Awesome v1.0.0\n"; });
  CommonOptionsParser Options(Argc, Argv, MyToolOptions);
  ClangTool Tool(Options.getCompilations(), Options.getSourcePathList());
  return 0;
}
```

Running this tool with `-version` option:

```sh
> ./myTool -version
Awesome v1.0.0
```

Happy hacking with Clang!

Comment: Thanks @Valeriy Savchenko. This is what I was looking for.